# How to access remote repositories using aliases?

Tags: git, config, alias, remote-access

Since I want to be able to `push` code using several identities/keys. To do this I defined some aliases for in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
#github.com default
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foo

#github.com-foo
Host github.com-foo
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foo

#github.com-bar
Host github.com-bar
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bar

...
```

To access my repos I use then the aliases, e.g.:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com-foo:MyOrganizationOrPersonalAccount/MyRepo.git
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com-foo:MyOrganizationOrPersonalAccount/MyRepo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com-foo:MyOrganizationOrPersonalAccount/MyRepo.git (push)
```

This has been working perfectly for long time. And now (probably since I reinstalled the OS) it doesn's work anymore:

```
$ git fetch
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**What might cause this issue and how to get the remote access working?**

**UPDATE**

I reinstalled Git to be shure, that I'm using the OpenSSH client. Now it works. So i guess the problem has been caused by using plink as SSH client, that doesn't consider the `~/.ssh/config` setting.

Comment: Your keys becoming invalid? Have you tried adding new keys?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Oh, sorry, just forgot to post the CLI output. Updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried this `ssh -T git@github.com` with your aliases?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error some time ago, to fix it i removed the remote form the list

```
git remote remove MyRemote
```

And then added it again, using the HTTP link instead if the ssh key

```
git remote add Http://URLToRepositoryHere
```

Comment: I don't need the HTTP link, I want to be able to `commmit`.

Comment: I had the same problem, and my problem was solved when I added the remote through the HTTP protocol. I was using Bitbucket as a remote and it seems as if they don't like you to use ssh. So after I switched to HTTP it all just worked fine, I could push and pull without problems.